# Is Kernel Model dependent on CS?

Tags: linux, kernel

How does Linux detect if the present code is being run in kernel mode or user mode?

Is it inherent to code section i.e., a specific code section can be run only in kernel mode (or user mode)?

Or can a code section be run in both kernel and user mode?

Comment: Kernel code doesn't "detect" it. It is written to be run in kernel mode. If your kernel code ever has to WONDER WHERE IT IS then you did something HORRIBLY WRONG.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thank you, I figured out that  last two bits of CS register store and 2nd bit of PTE stores User/kernel information.